# How to make ZNC replay what previously happened on the channel when I reconnect from a client?

Tags: irc, linode

I just set up ZNC and would like to, whenever connecting, grab the previous history of any channels I rejoin, with some exceptions. I'm using ZNC 1.4 and I have loosely followed this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-znc-an-irc-bouncer-on-an-ubuntu-vps to set ZNC up on my Linode server.